# AWS create RetryPolicy with multiple RetryConditions

Tags: aws-sdk

I am creating a client for DynamoDB and I would like to create `RetryPolicy` multiple `RetryCondition`. Is there a way to do that?

Following example has a retry client with one RetryPolicy:

```
   ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
        .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder().retryCondition(RetryOnExceptionsCondition.create(UnknownHostException.class))
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RetryOnExceptionsCondition::create` method takes vararg, a collection of exceptions that can be used in a `RetryPolicy`.

```java
RetryOnExceptionsCondition.create(UnknownHostException.class, SdkException.class)
```